# Trying to understand the limits of 'T extends infer U'

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I've understood that something like:

```js
type GenericExample<T> = T extends (infer U) ? U : 'bar';
```

is equal to:

```js
type GenericExample<T> = T extends T ? T : 'bar';
```

But when stuff becomes more elaborate, TypeScript complains:

```js
type Types = 'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params';

type MyExperiment<Type extends Types> =  { t : Type };

type MyExperimentsUnion = Types extends (infer U) ? MyExperiment<U> : never;
// Type 'U' does not satisfy the constraint 'Types'.
// Type 'U' is not assignable to type '"params"'.
```

So I'd like to ask why this is wrong: in this particular case distribution over union should take place, so the inferred `U` type should be `text`, then `date` and so on.
So, what does `T extends (infer U)` really mean and when it would be appropriate to use it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it was meant to be used the way you are using it - basically `infer` should be used in order to "infer" (or to resolve maybe better naming?) type, most commonly from a generic.

The way you are using it, you are creating a type that doesn't have any "dynamic" part (basically it's not generic), meaning it's always the same, and therefore inferring from something that is always the same doesn't make sense. Because at compile time you already know that `Types` extends only `Types & '...anything else'`, and since you can't define that other part in your `MyExperimentsUnion` type, `infer` doesn't have much of a use.

Example usage

```
interface Action<T> {
    payload: T
}

type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends Action<infer X> ? X : never

function getPayload<T extends Action<any>>(action: T): ExtractGeneric<T> {
    return action.payload;
}

const myAction = { payload: 'Test' };
const myPayloadWithResolvedType = getPayload(myAction);
```

In the example above `myPayloadWithResolvedType` would have `string` as resolved type, because if you weren't using `infer`, you'd have to pass that return type as second parameter probably like this:

```
function getPayloadNonExtract<T extends Action<U>, U>(action: T): U {
    return action.payload;
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAPAFQD5kBvAKGUuQAc4BPAGyzgBMAuZfMgXzLLDrUUAUQAeYKIjABxCCGjAEBYgF5OyCOLksAzmgzY8oGNGQANYgH5zyDvIBu0PjACuIAzmQBzCGAAK9EysBBpaILr6mDi4cCB0hIQAFFKGHPgAlBxiElKy8lCKyqQUVFC%20LlAgyCk4AHS0jMwsANw8fAg4OmDIALZ06FFVaiQ0gU0cAOT4EF0TyNytHSBdvXQBjawA6sBgABYASjNYDI4s%20IIoaj7%20Y6yJfQOG6a1kAPSvyDoQSyyhcD3UBgoADuO12WBc3WMTlc7kG3l86yCLAAcjhspIMCFNJBwnpHtEAKqEAA0yGJyQ8IDSmXJxSoyDKYAqVRqIHqtxabTISxWZR0x1O5yEyCuiM5aJAGKkuAJeC6BRAXlJnwkoGV936VOeQA) is the link to the playground.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your answer! I have to say that I know the general purpose of the `infer` keyword, but I've asked this weird question because I've discovered that `T extends (infer U)` is valid in a conditional type, I was surprised about that and I started investigating.

Comment: I think I understand your question, but I'm not sure how would you like typescript to resolve `U`? What should the `MyExperiment<U>` be? I mean, `U` must be "subclass" of `Types`, but typescript can't determine what exactly is `U` since you're not passing any type (it's not generic type), and I don't see why it should default to `Types`. I guess that's one of the reasons you get the error, although I agree it could be more descriptive, but it seems they're going with state of mind that developers should know that `infer` was not meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this was asked 1 year ago, but for anyone who is late to the party, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) it is.

I can't figure out how I missed this since it's right there in the docs, but as all of us here are in the same boat, let's see what's going on (starting from your code).

```
type Types = 'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params';

type MyExperiment<Type extends Types> =  { t : Type };

// We can drop the parentheses around "infer U" as they do nothing here
type MyExperimentsUnion = Types extends infer U ? MyExperiment<U> : never;
// Type 'U' does not satisfy the constraint 'Types'.
```

In your code, you only capture `Types` using the `infer` keyword, but that doesn't tell typescript anything about `U`, so even though you will see this:

```
type foo = Types extends infer U ? U : never;
// foo will show up as 'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params'
```

And wonder "Well, isn't `U` then of type `'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params'`? Why is it not assignable to `MyExperiment<>`?". **My guess*** is that the union type is only resolved at the end of the conditional, so it is not technically available when you assign it as a type parameter to `MyExperiment<>`.

If you wanted to do this with `infer` and distribute the type, you would have to add an extra condition, to constrain `U` at that time, to ensure that it is available as the correct type when you use it as a type parameter in `MyExperiment<>`.

```
type MyExperimentsUnion =
    Types extends infer U ?
        U extends Types ?
            MyExperiment<U>
        : never
    : never;
// MyExperiment<"text"> | MyExperiment<"date"> | MyExperiment<"articles"> | MyExperiment<"params">
```

Your example, however, could be also done like this

```
type MyExperimentsUnion<T extends Types = Types> = T extends any ? MyExperiment<T> : never;
// When you use MyExperimentsUnion with no type parameter, it will be
// MyExperiment<"text"> | MyExperiment<"date"> | MyExperiment<"articles"> | MyExperiment<"params">
```

---

***** *I am explicitly stating that it is my guess because I haven't really studied how TypeScript evaluates this.*

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not worth more than two cents but:

```
type Types = 'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params';
type MyExperiment<Type extends Types> =  { t : Type };

type MyExperimentsGenericUnion<T extends Types> = T extends (infer U) ? MyExperiment<U> : never;
// same error

type MyExperimentsUnionConstraint = any extends MyExperiment<infer U> ? MyExperiment<U> : never;
// no error
```

I can think of a few reasons why `MyExperimentsUnionConstraint` works but `MyExperimentsUnion` doesn't, but I don't have the in depth language knowledge to express them so that it makes sense.

To give an explanation by example:

- in `MyExperimentsUnion`, from `Types extends U`, `U` could be inferred as `Types | 'bla'` and then `MyExperiment<Type | 'bla'>` doesn't work.
- in `MyExperimentsUnionConstraint`, `U` can only be inferred as something that works with `MyExperiment`